# SQL get next date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have 3 Tables in SQL SERVER

1. JOBS

```
JobID LastRunDateTime
1     01/02/2015
2     05/02/2015
3     20/01/2015
```

2. JobsDays - the days that the jobs need to run

```
JobID DayNum
1     1
1     2
1     5
2     2
2     6
3     1
3     2
3     3
```

3. JobTimes - the hours that the jobs nees to run

```
JobID TimeNum
1     12
1     13
2     10
2     20
3     7
```

I need to calculate the next time the job need to run.

I start to find the next date (without time) like this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime DATETIME
SET @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()

SELECT j.JobID,
       MIN(DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((jday.DayNum + 5 ) % 7 ), @CurrentDateTime) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((jday.DayNum + 5 ) % 7)))
     AS NEXTDATE
FROM Jobs j
    JOIN JobDays jday on j.JobID = jday.JobID
    group by j.JobID
```

I get the next date to run, but I need the full datetime of the next run.

Thanks

Comment: Why DISTINCT when you're already doing GROUP BY? BTW, sometimes j, sometimes job...

Comment: How do you compute for the next date to run?

Comment: @jarlh I edited the question.
next date to run is: the next date and time from the last run

Answer (score 1):

I would start by getting the first day of the current week:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @WeekStart DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

Which when run today (5th Feb) gives `2015-02-05`

Then you will need a cartesian product of days and times for each job, e.g. for job 1 you would end up with:

```
DayNum  Time
---------------
1       12
1       13
2       12
2       13
5       12
5       13
```

This would be done by using

```
SELECT  d.DayNum, t.TimeNum
FROM    Jobdays AS d
        INNER JOIN JobTimes AS t
            ON t.JobID = d.JobID
WHERE   d.JobID = 1
```

Then it is just a case of adding these days and times to the start of the week:

```
DayNum  TimeNume    Date/Time
---------------------------------------
1       12          2015-02-03 12:00:00
1       13          2015-02-03 13:00:00
2       12          2015-02-04 12:00:00
2       13          2015-02-04 13:00:00
5       12          2015-02-07 12:00:00
5       13          2015-02-07 13:00:00
```

Using:

```
DATEADD(HOUR, t.TimeNum, DATEADD(DAY, d.DayNum - 1, @WeekStart))
```

The problem is that right at the end of the week, you will end up with going into the next week to find the next run date, so you need to generate two weeks worth of dates and times by adding a further join:

```
SELECT  d.DayNum, 
        t.TimeNum,
        RunDateTime = DATEADD(WEEK, w.WeekNum, DATEADD(HOUR, t.TimeNum, DATEADD(DAY, d.DayNum - 1, @WeekStart)))
FROM    Jobdays AS d
        INNER JOIN JobTimes AS t
            ON t.JobID = d.JobID
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1)) AS w (WeekNum)
WHERE   d.JobID = 1;
```

So bringing it all together, you end up with

```
DECLARE @WeekStart DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
WITH JobDays AS
(   SELECT  JobID, DayNum
    FROM    (VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 2), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)) t (JobID, DayNum)
), JObTimes AS
(   SELECT  JObID, TimeNum
    FROM    (VALUES (1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 10), (2, 20), (3, 7)) t (JobID, TimeNum)
), RunDates AS
(   SELECT  d.JobID,
            RunDateTime = DATEADD(WEEK, w.WeekNum, DATEADD(HOUR, t.TimeNum, DATEADD(DAY, d.DayNum - 1, @WeekStart)))
    FROM    Jobdays AS d
            INNER JOIN JobTimes AS t
                ON t.JobID = d.JobID
            CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1)) AS w (WeekNum)
)
SELECT  JobID,
        NextRunDateTime = MIN(RunDateTime),
        NextRunDate = CAST(MIN(RunDateTime) AS DATE),
        NextRunTime = CAST(MIN(RunDateTime) AS TIME)
FROM    RunDates
WHERE   RunDateTime > GETDATE()
GROUP BY JobID;
```

Which gives:

```
JobID |    NextRunDateTime  | NextRunDate| NextRunTime
------+---------------------+------------+---------
1     | 2015-02-05 12:00:00 | 2015-02-05 | 12:00:00
2     | 2015-02-06 10:00:00 | 2015-02-06 | 10:00:00
3     | 2015-02-08 07:00:00 | 2015-02-08 | 07:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't explain that DayNum is the day in week. For example 1= Sunday, 2= Monday etc...

Comment: I know, the answer is based on that assumption. However, I did forget to remove 1 from the daynum, I have made that edit now

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. write as:

`DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()) 
 + (MIN(jTime.TimeNum -DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())))AS NEXTTIME`

as:

```
SELECT distinct Job.JobID,
       MIN(DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((jday.DayNum + 5 ) % 7 )
      , @CurrentDateTime) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((jday.DayNum + 5 ) % 7)))
      AS NEXTDATE
      ,DATEPART(HH,GETDATE()) 
      + (MIN(jTime.TimeNum -DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())))AS NEXTTIME
FROM @Jobs job
    JOIN @JobsDays jday on job.JobID = jday.JobID
    JOIN @JobsTimes jTime ON jday.JobID = jTime.JobID
 group by job.JobID
```